# How to make VoiceOver treat a UITableView as a single accessibility element?

Tags: ios, uitableview, voiceover

In a special use case I want a `UITableView` to be a single accessibility element instead of a container exposing its cells to `VoiceOver`.

I tried setting its `isAccessibilityElement` to `true` and assigning its `accessibilityLabel` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a `UITableView` to be a single accessibility element instead of a container exposing its cells to `VoiceOver`.

Unfortunately, **it's impossible as is**.
You can code it with no warning because you deal with an informal protocol but it won't be interpreted by `VoiceOver`: it's a mess because you do the same thing on a `tableView` as on a simple `label`for instance but it doesn't work here.
I have no technical proof but I think that a `tableView` isn't meant to be an accessible element, only its cells should.

> I tried setting its isAccessibilityElement to true and assigning its accessibilityLabel but it didn't work [...] when I swipe left and right, VoiceOver goes through the cells and doesn't pronounce the table view's `accessibilityLabel`.

A `UITableView` may be seen as a container inside which many elements are embedded *(its cells)* and, as is, you can't have simultaneously a parent view *(the table view)* and its child views *(its cells)* that are [both accessible](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements) with VoiceOver: either the table view can be selected or its cells.

If you don't want to swipe through the cells, insert the code snippet hereafter:

```
myTableViewInsideTheCell.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
```

Then, `VoiceOver` is informed that elements inside the table view mustn't be interpreted.
Now, as the table view can't be seen as an accessible element, just create one inside your table view cell:

```
let a11yElt = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: myTableViewCell.contentView)
a11yElt.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = myTableViewInsideTheCell.frame
a11yElt.accessibilityTraits = .staticText
a11yElt.accessibilityLabel = "my table view inside the cell is now accessible."

myTableViewCell.accessibilityElements = [a11yElt]
```

This element overlaps your table view inside the cell and can be treated as any other accessible element with the common properties.

I think many other ways are possible to reach your goal but, following this rationale, you could **make VoiceOver treat a UITableView as a single accessibility element**.

You have the guideline, now it's up to you to implement/adapt it in your environment to reach your goal.